# How to randomly select a single value in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I was searching forever to find an answer to this and no one seemed to have asked, so I am asking and providing my answer here.

How do you randomly select a single cell value in pandas data frame?

It is really simple. I was struggling finding the syntax for the formula. Also I was making the mistake of not starting my count from 0.

```
random_first_message = data_frame.loc[randint(0,7), 'First_Message']
```

This code selects a random row between 0 and 7, then selects the the column First_Message and provides that to the variable random_first_message.

Comment: To make this more dynamic you could add a len(data_frame) in the randint so it will know to look between 0 and the length of your dataframe without hardcoding `random_first_message = data_frame.loc[randint(0,len(data_frame)), 'First_Message']`

Comment: You need .sample() function, works for pd.Series or pd.Dataframe: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn yes I want to do this but my data frame length in other columns is 680+. And the column of messages is only 7 in length. I could use the dynamic length of the specific column I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Quick example:

```
#generating an random string df
from pandas._testing import rands_array
randstr = pd.util.testing.rands_array(10, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=randstr, columns=["First_Message"])
df
```

Result:

| index | First_Message |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | cl3pf7uYI7 |
| 1 | C6ZmXvu8Fy |
| 2 | QcK6sHfRHS |
| 3 | p59ZNSA9Bs |
| 4 | ctNlg0X23n |
| 5 | vGqXIyF95L |
| 6 | Bwr9ECqhst |
| 7 | Wam6VmgLbu |
| 8 | DniZeLQXNx |
| 9 | LH3QMGRrG6 |

Then simply chose the column and the number of sample(s) like this:

```
df['First_Message'].sample(3)

3    p59ZNSA9Bs
8    DniZeLQXNx
6    Bwr9ECqhst
Name: First_Message, dtype: object
```

Comment: Ahh I see. Much easier. Let me try that. Thanks!